# Fourier Transform involving frequency differentiation property

Tags: math, fourier

Going through some past exams, I've came across this question;

[image: question]

To get started, I've noticed that it resembles to the frequency differentiation property;
[image: working]

Now, the differentiation was extremely messy, and as a result, the second derivative was worse than the [first](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+-%288+i+e%5E%28-5+i+x%29+%2880-2+i+x%2B5+x%5E2%29%29%2F%2816%2Bx%5E2%29%5E2)

Is there another property that I can use to simplify this problem or the only is using this derivative? The formula sheet we used for this paper is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8oXY.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3ZNp.png)

Answer (score 1):

I would treat it as two step functions added together by splitting the absolute value.
t^2*exp(-4*(t-5))*u(t-5) + t^2*exp(-4*-(t-5))*u(-t+5) - dirac(t-5)

Then you can use the "nth-order time-rising causal delay exponential function" transform. Since they're added together, you can use superposition. The dirac part of it removes the discontinuity that would occur at t=5.

Comment: But for that "nth-order time-rising causal delay exponential function" you need all the t's to be the same, in this case some are shifted by 5, you can't use that.